# How to exclude all hidden folders except content of .config with fdfind?

Tags: fd

Using [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) also known as fdfind, how would I go about not including any hidden directories and files except for all the content in the .config directory?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a:

```
!.config/
```

To `~/.config/fd/ignore` (in gitignore format) seems to work.

It seems it still ignores files whose name starts with `.` inside `.config` directories. For example, `fdfind foo` will find `.config/foobar` or `.config/barfoo`, but not `.config/.foo` not `.config/.dir/foo`.

If you want those, add `!.config/**` line to that `ignore` file.